# Analyzing the performance of SQL queries between OnPrem and AWS environment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, query-optimization, datasource

I am working in modernizing an existing REST services and moving from OnPrem to AWS.

**The legacy application**

```
 deployed in a OnPrem Liberty Server 
 MS SQL server DB was used. 
 Spring/Hibernate was the core technologies.
```

***New Application Details :***

```
Spring Boot deployed in the AWS environment in a docker container 
Server-Tomcat embedded with the Spring boot.
Database is the existing MS Sql server and it is located OnPrem
```

Some queries which were earlier took less that 500ms to execute is now taking upto 2000ms. The queries,logic and other code related thigs are same between the legacy and the new application. We are not able to find why the queries are taking more time in this.

In the legacy application we had used the **server.xml** to configure the data source and in the new application we have configured the data source in the Spring boot **application.properties** . Below are the Datasource configurations:

**Liberty Server datasource :**

```
<dataSource id="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver - DataSource - JVM3" jndiName="jdbc/xxx" containerAuthDataRef="yyy" statementCacheSize="50" isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED">

       <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MSSQLJDBCLib"/>
      <properties.microsoft.sqlserver databaseName="dbName" serverName="servername.com" portNumber="9999" lockTimeout="2000" packetSize="4096" sendStringParametersAsUnicode="false" trustStorePassword="{xor}" beginTranForVendorAPIs="false" freeResourcesOnClose="false" jmsOnePhaseOptimization="false" reauthentication="false" preTestSQLString="SELECT 1" validateNewConnection="false" validateNewConnectionRetryInterval="3" errorDetectionModel="ExceptionMapping" nonTransactionalDataSource="false" name="Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver - DataSource - JVM3" enableMultithreadedAccessDetection="false" beginTranForResultSetScrollingAPIs="false" validateNewConnectionRetryCount="100" connectionSharing="1"/>
        <connectionManager agedTimeout="-1" connectionTimeout="180" maxIdleTime="300" maxPoolSize="30" minPoolSize="0" reapTime="240" purgePolicy="FailingConnectionOnly"/>

</dataSource>
```

**Spring Boot Datasource :**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server.com:9999;databaseName=dBName
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=30
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=180000
```

What may be the other parameters which can impact the query performance between the old and the new application?

Note : The ping time between the AWS servers and the OnPrem db takes less than 2ms (very negligible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. All the queries which we made to the database were doing an Index scan instead of index seek. That is because we missed the `sendStringParametersAsUnicode="false"` parameter in the Connection JDBC url.

We changed the connection url to take the required parameters and the queries ran perfectly fine.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server.com:9999;databaseName=dBName;packetSize=4096;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
```